# Assigning to a parameterized 2d Verilog array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a Verilog array defined as :

```
logic [ 0 : num_elements - 1 ] [ element_width - 1 ] some_array ;
```

I want to assign every array element with a vector that is all ones: "11...1".
I tried this but I get an error:

```
some_array <= { num_elements { element_width { 1'b1 } } } ;
```

What's the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign unpacked 2d array in SystemVerilog with a single line:

```
some_array <= '{ default: '1 };
```

Verilog cannot be done in a single line. It must use a for-loop:

```
for ( i = 0; i < num_elements; i = i +1)
  some_array[i] <= {element_width{1'b1}};
```

Comment: Suppose:
num_elements = 4
element_width = 8

Making it more complicated I want each element to get "0xFA"
So now - my ONLY option is to use the for-loop approach ?
There's no way to do it in a single line like in VHDL ?
some_array <= ( others => ( others => x"FA" ) ) ;

Comment: @shaiko the SystemVerilog `'{default:  }` approach will still work. Refer to the SystemVerilog LRM

Comment: It'll work for packed as well as unpacked array ?

Answer (score 1):

Since some_array is all packed, you can do

```
some_array <= '1;
```

Comment: What if it was unpacked ?

Comment: I'm looking for a syntax to assign each array element individually...similar to what I wrote in my example.

Comment: In your example, each element is a single bit. You might want to check out the `default:` clause of an array assignment pattern